# Ошибка в Angular Cli

Tags: angular2, webpack, angular-cli

Установил Angular-cli. Применил команды `ng new ...` и потом `ng serve`, которая выдала мне следующие ошибки:

> ERROR in multi main
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:4200/' in 'C:\Angular 2\strange-euphoria'
>    @ multi main
>
> ERROR in multi styles
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'style-loader' in 'C:\Angular 2\strange-euphoria'
>    @ multi styles
>
> ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
>     Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js' in 'C:\Angular 2\strange-euphoria':
>     Error: Can't resolve 'html-webpack-plugin/lib/loader.js' in 'C:\Angular 2\strange-euphoria'

...

> ERROR in multi main
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@ngtools/webpack' in 'C:\Angular 2\strange-euphoria'
>    @ multi main

При этом делал все по туториалу https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5OLLPQq1GqQ&list=PL4cUxeGkcC9jqhk5RvBiEwHMKSUXPyng0&index=2

Comment: а ты уверен что сделал _ng serve_ в нужной папке?

Comment: В strange-euphoria перешел, которую до этого создал командой `nq new strange-euphoria`.

Comment: Похоже не все пакеты установились корректно. Судя по путям это винда, а там все не как у людей. Попробуйте сначала выполнить `npm install --global windows-build-tools`, а потом `npm install` в каталоге проекта.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется не установлены зависимости указанные в package.json или их установка не прошла успешно. Нужно удалить node_modules, очистишь кеш

```
npm cache clean
```

и установить зависимости через

```
npm install
```